# Show that $g$ a continuous map with the following properties is $az$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let us suppose that $g:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is a continuous map with the following properties:

1) $g(0)=0$,

2) $g(z)$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$,

3) $|g(z)|<c|z|$ for $|z|$ sufficiently large.

I need to prove that $g(z)=az$; where $a\in\mathbb{C}$.

From 3) follows that $\frac{g(z)}{z}$ is bounded and from 2) that $\frac{g(z)}{z}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$. Now, I only need to prove that $\frac{g(z)}{z}$ is holomorphic in the whole complex plane.

Do you have any suggestion that can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Since $z\mapsto\frac{g(z)}{z}$ is in modulus bounded by $c>0$, and since as you already pointed out such a function is holomorphic on $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$, we can conclude that it is bounded around $z_0=0$ which is thus a removable singularity, so you can extend this function to the whole $\Bbb C$; let's call $f$ the extension.

Now $f$ is an entire bounded function, which is constant by Liouville, i.e. $f\equiv a$, from which we get
$$
a=g(z)/z
$$
and conclude.